# Draw a simple graph in VB.NET / C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, math, graph

I am going insane with this, i've spent weeks trying to get it right and I think I am just burned out. Every time I get a working model and I change the HighestNumber / LowestNumber, it breaks and things are off screen.

I deleted all my actual running code a million times, so **this is psuedo code**, but roughly what i'm doing and I know the answer is so absolutely obvious.

I need the numbers to scale inside the client area and stay within bounds whether they're max (max 9,999,000 and min 0.01) or (max 1.00 and min 0.98)

The highest number should be on top, and the lowest number on bottom.

I will always know the Highest and Lowest numbers before iteration, those are basically to be used to scale the the graph as the high/low/cur can be ANY value.

[image: Graph explanation]

```
DIM HighestNumber as double = 1.33
DIM LowestNumber as double = 0.99
DIM GraphClientArea as single = 400
DIM HalfClientArea as single = GraphClientArea / 2

FOR x = 1 to 50 ' roll X for 500px total
    DIM r as new Random
    DIM CurX as single = X * 10 ' 10px blocks horiz
    DIM CurrentNumber as double = 1.02 + r.Next(-0.10,0.10) ' make up a random number in range

    DIM Spread as double = HighestNumber - LowestNumber
    DIM SpreadPercentage as Double = (LowestNumber / HighestNumber)

    DIM Y as double = (HalfClientArea * SpreadPercentage) - (SpreadPercentage * CurrentNumber) 

    g.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, New Rectangle(x, y, 2, 2))                                

NEXT
```

I know the above isn't right, I just can't figure out what the right algorithm is to accomplish what I need.

Comment: What things are off-screen? Why are the calculations for `Spread` and `SpreadPercentage` *inside* the loop when they are constants? Also, 1.02 - 0.10 = 0.92, which is less than 0.99.

Comment: The question isn't about programming semantics, as I said, it's psuedo code. I need the numbers to scale inside the client area and stay within bounds whether they're max (max 9,999,000 and min 0.01) or (max 1.00 and min 0.98)

Comment: I'm not asking for programming advice, as I said, IT IS PSUEDO CODE. It probably doesn't even compile.

Comment: @Undefined What things are off-screen?

Comment: Nothing is off screen, unless you jack the min/max to 10,000 or anything larger than client area.

Comment: @Undefined Do you want the random numbers to be within `LowestNumber` and `HighestNumber`?

Comment: The numbers are random just so you can see they will change, in fact, I will know a static number through a larger iteration of data points. But yes, it will be between highestnumber and lowest number always, and lowestnumber is never negative.

Comment: @Undefined Getting frustrated at us for not understanding the question isn't going to make us feel good about trying to help ;) Perhaps the question has been simplified too much, and some more detail would help us - we haven't been looking at it for weeks.

Comment: @AndrewMorton i'm not frustrated with you, i'm frustrated with the other guy who is analyzing psuedo-code like i'm about to insert it into a launch control system at SpaceX. It's made up for illustration.

Comment: Also, I figured it out. (clientArea - (clientArea * (Cur / Max))); pretty language inspecific huh?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.
Output:

[image]

The algebra to solve for Y is

> (clientArea - (clientArea * (Cur / Max)))

While arguing with a non-contributor, I likened the values I have to a progress bar, when the math finally hit me. All you're doing is making a progress bar and instead of drawing X,Y; you're drawing Y,X to make it vertical.

Test code for anyone who needs it

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint

        Dim clientArea As Single = PictureBox1.Height

        Dim Max As Single = 1207.43

        Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    
        Dim LastPoint As New Point(0, 0)

        Dim prices As New List(Of Double)
        prices.Add(1207.43)
        prices.Add(1107.2)
        prices.Add(1203.33)
        prices.Add(807.12)
        prices.Add(607.21)
        prices.Add(907.53)
        prices.Add(607.61)
        prices.Add(1000.43)

        For i = 0 To prices.Count - 1
            Cur = prices(i)

            Dim col = i * 100
            Dim y As Single = (clientArea - (clientArea * (Cur / Max)))


            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, New Rectangle(col, y, 10, 10))
            g.DrawString(Cur.ToString, Me.Font, Brushes.Black, New Point(col + 12, y))

            g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, LastPoint, New Point(col, y))

            LastPoint = New Point(col, y) ' cur vector becomes prev vector for next iteration

        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: You really really need to set `Option Strict On`: some issues will come out that you need to fix: some *weird* values will appear here and there at some point. Use all `RectangleF` and all `PointF`. You could remove the calculation (`Dim y As Single = ...`) on every iteration by transforming the (x, y) Graphics origin vector beforehand. Even if this procedure is probably not performance-critical, keep it in mind for the future (those divisions and multiplications per iteration on mixed double/float values cost a lot). You have to re-evaluate this: `Dim col = i * 100`.

Answer (score -1):

This is my best guess as to what you are asking for. It is an update display routine, which has a new current value created based upon a timer and random values.

```
private void updateDisplay(bool clipToMaxMin)
{
    // get the graphics context for the panel
    var g = pnlCanvas.CreateGraphics();
    g.Clear(BackColor);

    // get the min and max width
    var minWidth = g.VisibleClipBounds.Left;
    var maxWidth = g.VisibleClipBounds.Right;
    // get the current width to use
    var curWidth = minWidth + ((maxWidth - minWidth) / 2.0f);

    // get the min and max height
    var minHeight = g.VisibleClipBounds.Bottom;
    var maxHeight = g.VisibleClipBounds.Top;

    // Have to decide if we are going to update max and min or
    // clip the values to max and min
    if(clipToMaxMin)
    {
        current = (current < min) ? min : (current > max) ? max : current;
    }
    else
    {
        if (current > max) max = current;
        else if(current < min) min = current;
   }

   var curScaled = (current - min) / (max - min);
   var curHeight = minHeight + ((maxHeight - minHeight) * (curScaled));

   g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, new RectangleF(curWidth, curHeight, 20, 20));
}
```